# How do you prevent sortedArrayUsingSelector from removing duplicate entries (ios)?

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, duplicates, nsdictionary

How can I use the following method to sort my array and **keep** the duplicates? All I want is to sort the distance array and have the lineItems array sort in the same order so that my line items are sorted by distance. Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried many different implementations with no luck.

```
lineItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)[data objectForKey:@"line_items"]];
distanceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[lineItems count]];
        for (int i = 0; i < [lineItems count]; i++) {
            CLLocation *spotLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[[lineItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue] longitude:[[[lineItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]];
            CLLocationDistance distance = ([myLocation distanceFromLocation:spotLocation] / 1000) * 0.621371192;
            NSNumber *foo = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:distance];
            [distanceArray insertObject:foo atIndex:i];
        }
```

My bubble sort implementation:

```
for (int i=0;i<[distanceArray count]-1;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<[distanceArray count];j++){
                if ([[distanceArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue] >[[distanceArray objectAtIndex:j]doubleValue]){
                    NSNumber *temp_i = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[distanceArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]];
                    NSNumber *temp_j = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[distanceArray objectAtIndex:j]doubleValue]];
                    [distanceArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                    [distanceArray removeObjectAtIndex:j];
                    [distanceArray insertObject:temp_j atIndex:i];
                    [distanceArray insertObject:temp_i atIndex:j];

                    NSDictionary *tempObj_i = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[lineItems objectAtIndex:i]];
                    NSDictionary *tempObj_j = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[lineItems objectAtIndex:j]];
                    [lineItems removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                    [lineItems removeObjectAtIndex:j];
                    [lineItems insertObject:tempObj_j atIndex:i];
                    [lineItems insertObject:tempObj_i atIndex:j];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is in `dictionary`?

Comment: Inafziger, I added more of the code

Comment: what method are you referring to? `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`?

Comment: yea, sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) is taking out the duplicates when it sorts them. this is messing up my indexing

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"DICTIONARY BEFORE %@", dictionary);` to your program and post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just turning the lineItems into array of mutable dictionaries and adding the distance into each line item. Then using the sortUsingDescriptor method. I appreciate everyone's help! Something so simple was so difficult for me... thanks:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [lineItems count]; i++) {
            CLLocation *spotLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[[lineItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue] longitude:[[[lineItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]];
            CLLocationDistance distance = ([myLocation distanceFromLocation:spotLocation] / 1000) * 0.621371192;
            NSNumber *foo = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:distance];

            NSMutableDictionary *newLineItem = [[lineItems objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
            [newLineItem setObject:foo forKey:@"distance"];
            [lineItems removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [lineItems insertObject:newLineItem atIndex:i];
            newLineItem = nil;
        }
        [lineItems sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES]]];
```

Comment: This code leaks (unless you're using ARC). You want to explicitly release `newLineItem` at the end of the loop. Setting it to `nil` just loses the reference to the `NSMutableDictionary` allocated by `-mutableCopy`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem isn't `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, it's `NSDictionary`'s `-allKeys` method. Keys are unique in a dictionary, so the `-allKeys` array won't have any duplicates.

Use a separate `NSArray` instance to store the result of the sort, or use inafziger's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your sort function, try this:

```
[distanceArray sortArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Then you don't need the dictionary at all.

Answer (score 0):

why not just do an old fashion bubble sort?

something like this:

```
distanceArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithOjects:[ distanceArray allKeys]];
for (int i=0;i<[distanceArray count]-1;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<[distanceArray count];j++){
        if ([[distanceArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue] >[[distanceArray objectAtIndex:j]floatValue]){
            id temp=[[distanceArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
            [distanceArray insertObject:[[distanceArray objectAtIndex:j]floatValue] atIndex:i];
            [distanceArray insertObject:temp atIndex:j];
        }
    }
}
```

and they're all sorted with duplicates (it's not pretty but it works)

edit:

if nothing works..make a objective c object with something like: coord1, coord2, distance, and maybe an unique id ..so you never have a duplicate item .Declare them as property to that object and then bubble sort them (with maybe changing the id-s too) .Like if you have an object with id=2 and you move it in array on index 1, then change the id to match the index...or something to that effect.Then you wont need the dictionary cuz you have the coord in the object itself...it should be easier to do ..at least in my mind

Comment: tried this bubble sort and was getting an infinite loop until i removed the objects before swapping them. however, this is still sorting the numbers out of order. I added my implementation of your bubble sort in the above description. Any clues as to what's going wrong?

Comment: my goal is very simple, i want to sort the distance array and have line items sorted in the exact same way so that my line items are sorted by distance. for some reason this has been very difficult for me in ios...

Comment: what are you doing with the dictionary? if i understand this corectly, you are trying to save in a dictionary where the key is a value and the object is another value. That's wrong! dictionary overrides the previous value for a given key...so instead either use 2 arrays or look into NSSet (tho NSSet is a subclass of NSArray..so..yea..same thing)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I made the above explanation more clear (sorry please check it again as I left in the old code by accident) based on your bubble sort but am still having issues. lineItems is an array of dictionaries. each of those dictionaries has a latitude and longitude. I use those coordinates to create an array of distances. I want to sort the distance array but also have the lineItems array sort along with it in the same order. Perhaps there's a more elegant way to do this?